# Which Jakarta ee version is compatible with Java 10?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am currently migrating a project to jdk 10, and since the Java.xml.* have been deprecated, I have used Jakarta ee instead.

Which Jakarta ee version is compatible with Java 10?

Comment: OK. What's the question?

Comment: which jakarta ee version is compatible with java 10?

Comment: Go for Java 11.

Comment: Is it compatible with Java 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which Jakarta EE version is compatible with Java 10?

I don't know if that is actually an answerable question.  Java / Jakarta EE is fundamentally a set of specifications.  The specifications do not prescribe a specific Java SE platform or compatibility requirements<sup>1</sup>.

So what you should really be doing is selecting the EE *implementation* you intend to use (e.g. Glassfish, JBoss, WebSpere, Weblogic, Wildfly and so on) based on the versions of Java that they require.

Having said that, you should not be targeting Java 10 as an execution platform.  It has reached its *end of life*.  You should either target Java 11 (which currently the latest Java LTS release) or the latest non-LTS release.  But beware that non-LTS Java releases only have a life time of 6 months.

At this point in time (2 years after its end-of-life) it is likely that most Java EE implementations will no longer (officially) support Java 10 as an execution platform.

---

<sup>1 - Exception: the draft for Jakarta EE 9 requires that the underlying Java platform supports *at least* Java SE 8.</sup>

Comment: How about the maven dependency to Jakarta EE 8, is this compatible with Java 11 on a maven project? I just want to use the jaxb package, and that is why I ask if there are any compatibility issues.´

Comment: Do the Java EE implementations (Jakarta, glassfish etc) require a specific Java version, don't they?

Comment: @Stephen C , how do I know what version of JavaEE or JackartaEE is my application using?  Thanks

Comment: Look at the imports in your app's source code.  Do you see `javax` imports or `jakarta` imports?